# How to hide colorbar/legend in altair?

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to hide the color bar on Altair?

Specifically, I want to get rid of the `amount_spent`one, without deleting the gradiente on the `mark_bar`. Is this possible?

Here's the code:

```
alt.Chart(df_1).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('amount_spent:Q', title = "Monto gastado en MXN"),
    y = alt.Y('page_name:N', sort='-x', title = " "),
    color='amount_spent',
).transform_window(
  rank='rank(amout_spent))',
  sort=[alt.SortField('amount_spent', order='descending')]
).transform_filter(
  alt.datum.rank <= 20
).properties(
    width = 800,
    height= 500,
    title = "Monto gastado en MXN por página de FB"
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by setting the `legend` property of the `color` encoding to `None`; that is, replace this:

```python
color='amount_spent'
```

with this:

```python
color=alt.Color('amount_spent', legend=None)
```

See [Adjusting the Legend](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#adjusting-the-legend) in the Altair documentation for more information.